# after upgrading magento 2.2.3 to 2.4.4 all pub files return 404

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, 404

I just upgraded my Magento setup from 2.2.3 to 2.4.4 and all went good but after running setup:upgrade command i tried to access the website and it load without any php error but all files serving from "pub" directory giving 404 error, their path doesn't contain "pub".

This is the error in the URL for all of the files:

```
GET https://domain.com/media/wysiwyg/icon4.png 404
```

and the path should be here

```
https://domain.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icon4.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

**Step:1**. Add this in *app/etc/env.php*

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'web' => [
            'unsecure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ],
            'secure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Step:2**. Run `bin/magento app:config:import` or `bin/magento setup:upgrade` if there is any error.